# How to write jQuery or JavaScript equivalent for CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to have an jQuery equivalent to CSS which when tab is clicked shows it content. For now, I'm able to get this from CSS only. I would like to have same function with jQuery or Javascript.

For example, now when SUN is clicked, it shows "It is Sunday" and when MON is clicked, it shows "It is Monday" and so on.

How can I have same functionality from jQuery or Javascript?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 2px;
  background: #E5E4E2;
}

.tabinator {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.tabinator input {
  display: none;
}

.tabinator label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0.6%;
  color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  font-family: courier;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.tabinator label:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.tabinator label:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabinator input:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.tabinator input:checked+label:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}

#content1,
#content2,
#content3,
#content4,
#content5,
#content6,
#content7 {
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#tab1:checked~#content1,
#tab2:checked~#content2,
#tab3:checked~#content3,
#tab4:checked~#content4, 
#tab5:checked~#content5,
#tab6:checked~#content6,
#tab7:checked~#content7 {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabinator">

  <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">SUN</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">MON</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab3" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">TUE</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab4" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">WED</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab5" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab5">THU</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab6" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab6">FRI</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab7" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab7">SAT</label>

  <div id="content1">
    <p> This is Sunday</>
  </div>

  <div id="content2">
    <p> This is Monday</p>
  </div>

  <div id="content3">
    <p> This is Tuesday</p>
  </div>

  <div id="content4">
    <p> This is Wednesday</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content5">
    <p> This is Thursday</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content6">
    <p> This is Friday</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="content7">
    <p> This is Saturday</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please review [ask] and update your question to have a clear problem statement. As it stands now you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: @zzzzBov, I hope it might works.

Comment: Check this out: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @DanielD no wonder , it is great resource and I will go through it. But It would take a while to find the solution of above which I need sooner to close the project. But anyway thanks

Comment: Ok so say you wanted to style the content1 element. To do this with jquery you would write `$('#content1').css({'display' : 'none', 'border-top' : '1px solid #bbb', 'padding' : '3px', 'margin-top' : '2px'});`. It would be the same format for anything you wanted to style.

Comment: @DanielD well it was not I mean to say, I'm sorry for not being very informative. I would like to jquery equivlent to css to get the content of tabs when clicked just like in above give snippet. For eg when I clicked SUN, it shows It is sunday and when MON, it shows monday and so on

Comment: @SagarRawal Ok here check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/uhujpzst/3/. Now when you click on a radio button, it'll say what day it is. I'm just guessing this is what you meant.

Comment: @DanielD yes this what I needed so far, I will get back to you and will let you know if it worked or not. and One question? Can't I have same css styles as above in snippets for tabs color andbackground same except script and use what you have suggested instead.

Comment: @SagarRawal So each time you click on a day, do you want that matching content div to have those styles? I.e. you click on monday and it styles the monday content div?

Comment: @DanielD yes and I would like to have a tabs look a like rather then check buttons like I have above in snippets. Main importanty, I was looking for solutions to get solutions just like what you suggested which is solved but everything i.e styles stays the same. i.e container , background color and tab styles everything.

Comment: @SagarRawal Ok so I think you want to style each div differently here? Like such? https://jsfiddle.net/uhujpzst/4/. Or when you say "tabs look alike" do you mean the radio buttons or the content divs?

Comment: @DanielD yes , it is what I'm looking for. Now one more steps ahead. Right now It only shows the content inside of div only when clicked. How can I show the contents as the page loads according to day. Like if it is sunday, it would show the contents of Sunday i. e it is sunday without need to click, and if it monday it would show contents of monday itself i.e "It is monday"

Comment: @SagarRawal Ok so that would take a bit more coding. I can help out more tomorrow, but in the meantime here is some code to tell you what day of the week it is: https://jsfiddle.net/uhujpzst/8/. EDIT: Actually here is a quick example of how you can target the content divs based on what day it is: https://jsfiddle.net/uhujpzst/10/

Comment: @DanielD well yes I also using code to display the content as per the day from previous design. I can take help of it. But for now as sun is default value and is checked when page loads, but it won't show the content although it is checked. Only when I click it then it shows. I'm struggling it with now and once it is resolved, that would be my final call.

Comment: @SagarRawal Did you check out the second fiddle? Even though you have sun set as the default value, it still highlights the thu (today's) div. https://jsfiddle.net/uhujpzst/12/

Comment: @DanielD and as I mentioed that using Display:block,( for example in sun <div> ) solved the problem but it remains presistent there even if I click checked another input. i.e when page reloads , it shows the contents of sunday which I want , but now if i click mon, then it'd show content of both sun and mon on top of another. Similar with Tue where it shows content of Sun and Tue on top of each other

Comment: @SagarRawal So in that case you'll need to remove that class when you click on another input.

Comment: @DanielD well let's forget about the showing the tabs as per the day, I'll handle that one as I already tested my old one and it works very well. Now my final take is to show the content of input as the page loads which for now only show when clicked even though it is checked.

Comment: @SagarRawal So you want the page to load, and as soon as it loads you want to show the div based on what day it is, right?

Comment: @DanielD yes I want to show the day and it's content too. for eg if it is friday, then as soon the page loads, it should automatically check the fri and also show the contents of it. For eg "It is friday" for now. But now although it check the day but don't show the contents which only appears when I clicked the Fri after page loads.

Comment: @SagarRawal Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/uhujpzst/14/. This will load up and display the content for that day and also show the text for what day it is. Note though that this is just a proof on concept and will only work for thursday as that's all the if statement is checking for. To account for other days, you would have to use if/else to check for each day or use a switch statement.

Comment: @DanielD Here is the fiddle I have which loads the day as per the today's Date https://jsfiddle.net/BlueYeti/tcqjaetj/, only problem is that It doesn't show the contents as the page loads and only appears content inside <p> </p> when clicked. Can you have a look and yes I checked out above, It is not working but still I'm trying.

Comment: @SagarRawal I redid a few things from your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tcqjaetj/5/. This will check for each day on load, set the correct tab and show the proper content div.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because on SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your suitable ? (see snippet)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        padding: 2px;
        background: #E5E4E2;
    }
    ul#daysList {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 1px 1px 0 1px;
        font-family: Open Sans;
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    }
    ul#daysList li {
        position: relative;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
        width: 70px;
        height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 030px;
        color: #ccc;
        margin-bottom: -5px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        font-family: courier;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    ul#daysList li:hover {
        color: red;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    ul#daysList li.currentDay {
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    ul#daysList li.currentDay:after {
        display: block;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
    }
    .content {
        display: none;
        border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
        padding: 0 7px;
        margin-top: 0;
        background: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 38px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
    }
    .currentContent {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="daysList">
        <li data-day="content1" class="currentDay">SUN</li>
        <li data-day="content2">MON</li>
        <li data-day="content3">TUE</li>
        <li data-day="content4">WED</li>
        <li data-day="content5">THU</li>
        <li data-day="content6">FRI</li>
        <li data-day="content7">SAT</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content1" class="content currentContent">
        <p> This is Sunday</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content2" class="content">
        <p> This is Monday</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content3" class="content">
        <p> This is Tuesday</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content4" class="content">
        <p> This is Wednesday</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content5" class="content">
        <p> This is Thursday</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content6" class="content">
        <p> This is Friday</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content7" class="content">
        <p> This is Saturday</p>
    </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
        $(function () { // Jquery ready. for complete page loaded

            $("#daysList li").click(function () {
                var
                content_id = "#"+ $(this).data("day");

                $("#daysList li").removeClass("currentDay");
                $(this).addClass("currentDay");

                $(".content").removeClass("currentContent");
                $(content_id).addClass("currentContent");
            });
        }); // Jquery
</script>
</body>
</html>
```